# Parsing digits from command line argv

Tags: regex, perl

I want to change a perl script that executes a loop some times, and I want to pass the number of loops by command line option. The program now receives some options, then I need to change it to receive a new parameter, but it is the first time I see a perl script, then I don't know how to change.
The start of program (to parse command line options) is:

```
if ($#ARGV >= 1) {
   for ($i = 1; $i <= $#ARGV; $i++) {
       if ($ARGV[$i] =~ /^\-/) {
           if ($ARGV[$i] =~ /\-test/) {
               //do something
           }
       } else {
            //do something other
       }
  }
}
```

I think that I must put something like:

```
if ($ARGV[$i] =~ /^\-L40/)
```

But it only match to 40, I don't know how to parse the number attached to the -L parameter to use for the loop limit.

Thanks in advance and sorry if there is any similar question, but I don't find any.

Comment: You need some kind of GetOpt library. For example: http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html

Comment: Don't parse the options yourself.  Use the core Getopt::Long module.

Comment: Use `$ARGV[$i] =~ m/^-L(\d+)$/` if you persist in this approach, but you'd do better with Getopt::Std or Getopt::Long (to name but two standard modules; there are perhaps 40 other variants on Getopt in the CPAN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
my $loopLimit = 1;  # default

if ($#ARGV >= 1)
{
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $#ARGV; $i++)
  {
    if ($ARGV[$i] =~ /^\-/)
    {
      if ($ARGV[$i] =~ /\-test/)
      {
          # do something
      }
      elsif ($ARGV[$i] =~ /\-L(\d+)/)  # -L followed by digits
      {
          $loopLimit = $1;
      }
    }
    else
    {
        # do something other
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And what if somebody using the script runs it like `/path/to/script -L 17` (with a space between the flag and the value)?

Comment: Just explaining the problem as given, so OP understands what's needed for that to work. I completely agree that using one of the CPAN modules is the better move.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, I read that is better to use GetOptions, but I want to change as less as possible from existing program...

Comment: Then you still have lots and lots of code to write. For example, that doesn't give an error for that doesn't handle `-L12D`

Comment: There is no real problem in that now, I can accept this issue

Answer (score 4):

```
use Getopt::Long qw( );

sub usage {
   print(STDERR "usage: prog [--test] [-L NUM]\n");
   exit(1);
}    

GetOptions(
   'test' => \my $opt_test,
   'L=i'  => \my $opt_L,
)
   or usage();

die("-L must be followed by a positive integer\n")
    if defined($opt_L) && $opt_L < 1;
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `L=i` to have Getopt::Long require a number after the `-L` option?  Then you'd not need the `die`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, Cause I operated from memory, which didn't include `i`. The `die` is still needed since looping a negative number of times is very hard to do! Fixed.